# How to get all childs of root node in jtree?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I want to get all child nodes of root node.

ex:

```
Root
   child1
      child1.child1
   child2
      child2.child1
```

Now I want to get the two child nodes called "child1" and "child2".

How to do that? Is there any possibilities?

Please help me, Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Get the root of the tree:

```
 tree.getModel().getRoot();
```

then get the number of children of this root node:

```
 tree.getModel().getChildCount(rootNode)
```

then go from 0 to the number of children and call

```
tree.getModel().getChild(rootNode, i)
```

to get the children of the root node.

Comment: Thanks i got the answer. pls tell me how to remove all child nodes of that root node.

Comment: you forgot the parameter in the second :-)

Comment: But this doesn't check children inside children ?

Answer (score 6):

If your elements implement the `TreeNode` interface, you can use the available methods:

- [`TreeNode#children`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeNode.html#children%28%29)
- [`TreeNode#getChildAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeNode.html#getChildAt%28int%29)
- [`TreeNode#getChildCount`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeNode.html#getChildCount%28%29)

Otherwise, you can directly query the `TreeModel`. See the

- [`TreeModel#getRoot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeModel.html#getRoot%28%29)
- [`TreeModel#getChild`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeModel.html#getChild%28java.lang.Object,%20int%29)

methods